# Changing parent in MacFamilyTree

Tags: macfamilytree

In MacFamilyTree, if a person has been assigned the wrong parent, is it possible to reassign it to another parent?

Currently, the only way I know how to do this is to delete the person and create a new one, which takes a lot of time and is error prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Go either into the `Person` view or the `Family` view.

At the bottom you will find the children of a person/family. When you hover over a child, a small gearwheel will appear. When clicking it, you can choose the option *Remove Person from Family* from the menu. You can add the person to another family then.

You don’t need to delete the person.

[image: Choose "Remove Person from Family"]

Comment: Thanks, this works! It could be worth to mention that in order to connect the person to another parent, you must click on the cogwheel of "Add Mother or ..." or "Add Father of ...".